# Character limited in cell table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two widgets in my Excel file: Test1 and Test2

In my Test 1, I have a table with:

- A1: get some text
- A2: =@Pac[ReferenceClient] (I have the possibilities to retrieve the data in the other widget (Test2))

[image]

In my test2:

- A1: PAC (only text)

and in the table get:

- A2: ReferenceClient (only text)
- A3: Test (only text)

[image]

The problem is that I'm trying to add this text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries
```

And The text show me only:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has su
```

I don't understand why I have a limitation, if someone can explain me for sollve this problem, Thank you

Share my file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjfZR1l2-eadhwHhpXmid8R2ITZO?e=ED3ZB8

Comment: Can you please share the file? That will make resolving the issue easier

Comment: @lisboakotor https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjfZR1l2-eadhwHhpXmid8R2ITZO?e=ED3ZB8

Answer (score 0):

[https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/sp%C3%A9cifications-et-limites-relatives-%C3%A0-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:~:text=218%20caract%C3%A8res%20%E2%80%93%20Cela%20inclut%20le%20chemin%20d'acc%C3%A8s%20du%20fichier](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/sp%C3%A9cifications-et-limites-relatives-%C3%A0-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:%7E:text=218%20caract%C3%A8res%20%E2%80%93%20Cela%20inclut%20le%20chemin%20d%27acc%C3%A8s%20du%20fichier).

I understand the problem, the maximum number of characters in a header or footer is 255.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).